# [Python][Flask] Getting 404 when I hit rest end point

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am new to python and flask , was learning it for one of my application. I tried to create one rest end point but Getting 404

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

when I hit below curl

```
   curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/send_verification_email' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "email": "sdsdsfs@gmail.com",
  "verification_code": "PQRST"
}
'
```

route python file is

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify
from app.services.email_service import send_verification_email
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

notification_bp = Blueprint('notification_bp', __name__)


@notification_bp.route('/send_verification_email', methods=['POST'])
def send_verification_email_route():
    response, status_code = send_verification_email()
    return jsonify(response), status_code
```

app.py is

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
from config import config

import logging

# Set the log level (choose the appropriate level based on your needs)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Define the log format (customize it according to your preferences)
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=log_format)

# Optionally, specify a log file to write the logs to a file
# logging.basicConfig(filename='notification_service.log', format=log_format)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)

from app.api.views import notification_bp
app.register_blueprint(notification_bp, url_prefix='/api')

#db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mail = Mail(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Are you sure the flask server is running?

Comment: yes, I am sure, it is running

Comment: Is it logging the connection attempt at all?

Comment: yes, it is logging

127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2023 21:39:18] "POST /api/send_verification_email HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: What does your config.py look like?

Comment: don't have any thing in config file except
DEBUG = True
MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = "dsdfdsfs@gmail.com"

Comment: I was able to hack your code down a bit (comment out send_verification_email call, put notification_bp into a file in the same directory so I can just have from myview import notification_bp, and made config.py just have config.py define config to be an empty class) and when I run the curl command I get INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2023 12:47:54] "POST /api/send_verification_email HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: The DEBUG and MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER are in a class config: block, though, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254707/discussion-between-saurabh-garg-and-malcolm).

Comment: Sorry I got called away, and then didn't see your message until now.  My apologies.  I hope you have been able to make progress, but if you would like to continue the discussion, please respond.  I'll try to keep a better eye out.